Kotlin callback-based apis with more than one method
I have a use case called "RegisterDeviceUseCase" with a function "execute()".
I want this function to call a bluetooth adapter to get some information from the peripheral, and with the result, call a rest api and make execute() return the result from the rest call.
Something like:
suspend fun execute(): RestResult {
        val bluetoothData = bluetoothAdapter.getData() //<-- wrong, getData() can't return anything

        val restResult = api.call(bluetoothData)
        
        return restResult
    }

The problem is that the operations from the bluetoothAdapter are callback-based apis, and I can't directly get a result from the methods, i will get them in the bluetooth callback:
class BluetoothAdapter {

        fun getData() {
            bluetooth.sendRequest()
        }

        private val gattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
            
            fun onDataReceived(data: Data){
                //response received here, send this to usecase "execute" method
            }

            .
            .
            .
            
            //more callback methods

        }

    }

Is there a way to call the bluetoothadapter, wait for the response in the callback and then make the rest call with it?
I know there is callbackFlow but I think it only works with one-method callbacks, which is not the case with the bluetooth callback.
Maybe getData() could return a flow and I could collect the result in the usecase, but at some point I would need to stop collecting, since I don't want the use case to be collecting forever and I don't know if that's possible.
Thanks!

callbackFlow is appropriate, and it can handle multi-callback listeners. It's up to you to decide how you pass the results of all those methods into the flow.  But I don't know enough about what you're specifically doing to be able to suggest the way to implement this. Like, does the BluetoothAdapter class need to subscribe to the results, and keep listening for results after this getData() function has already returned something to the execute function? Or do you just want to get one specific thing back and finish up (such that you don't need a helper class at all, just a function)?

@Tenfour04 Thanks for answering. Yes, the bluetooth adapter needs to keep listening as long as the app lives with the "gattCallback" regardless of this usecase (or another) trying to get some data from outside. Also, for callbackflow with multi-callback listeners I assume I have to wrap all callback results in a class and send that to the flow, correct? Thanks

Since the results of all callbacks are merged into one flow they need to share a common super type. The usual way to go would be a sealed interface with concrete data classes/objects implementing that interface so you can differentiate between the callbacks.

Since you want the listener operating continually, where other classes can peek at most recent or next results, a SharedFlow is appropriate. I would create a MutableSharedFlow with the sealed type like Leviathan suggested. The adapter class can start the listener and the listener can report all the results into the SharedFlow.
